# ViewGroup cannot cover the view in RelativeLayout when API>20

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when API>20, `RelativeLayout` cannot cover the button, how to fix it without nesting `ViewGroup`?

Comment: What do you want this view to look like?

Comment: Button covered by RelativeLayout,just like in API 19 or below